# Query In operator in JPQL with CollectionTable

Tags: java, jpql

I have CandidateEntity, each CandiadateEntity has multiple job tags. I want to query all CandidateEntity have any job tag in given job tags list. How can I do it with CollectionTable as following code:

```
query = "SELECT c FROM CandidateEntity c JOIN c.jobFlags f WHERE f in :job_flags"

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @CollectionTable(name = "job_flags")
 @Column(name = "job_flag")
 private List<String> jobFlags;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<CandidateEntity> candidates= em.createQuery("SELECT c " +
    "FROM CandidateEntity c " +
    "WHERE :ids IN  c.jobFlags")
    .setParameter("ids",Arrays.asList(yourList)))
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@4755918f; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: Well this is amother error caused by somerhing else, can you try to print the list to see the results?